# apigee statistic collector/custom reports not working

Tags: statistics, report, analytics, apigee

I'm stuck at generating custom reports using Statistics Collector.

My scenario,

I have an BaaS DB with a collection named "icustomer" which has few name/value pair's.

I created a proxy(icustomer) to display an specific Customer(Resource name- specificcust) depending on unique "cust_id".

For Specific Customer I did "extract variable and assign variable policies" which is working fine.

Now to get custom reports I again added an Extract Variable policy to extract cust_id from JSON Path and then added and Statistic Collector policy to get stats.

Then I created an new report from Analytics and saved it. But reports aren't generated. All I get is "NO_ID" report.

Where did I go wrong?

Proxy Endpoint Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ProxyEndpoint name="default">
    <Description/>
<PreFlow name="PreFlow">
    <Request/>
    <Response/>
</PreFlow>
<Flows>
    <Flow name="specficcust">
        <Description/>
        <Request/>
        <Response/>
        <Condition>(proxy.pathsuffix MatchesPath &quot;/{cust_id}&quot;) and (request.verb = &quot;GET&quot;)</Condition>
    </Flow>
</Flows>
<PostFlow name="PostFlow">
    <Request/>
    <Response/>
</PostFlow>
<HTTPProxyConnection>
    <BasePath>/icustomer</BasePath>
    <VirtualHost>default</VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost>secure</VirtualHost>
</HTTPProxyConnection>
<RouteRule name="default">
    <TargetEndpoint>default</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>
 </ProxyEndpoint>
```

Target Endpoint Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TargetEndpoint name="default">
<Description/>
<PreFlow name="PreFlow">
    <Request/>
    <Response/>
</PreFlow>
<Flows>
    <Flow name="specficcust">
        <Description/>
        <Request>
            <Step>
                <FaultRules/>
                <Name>Extract-Variables-1</Name>
            </Step>
            <Step>
                <FaultRules/>
                <Name>Assign-Message-1</Name>
            </Step>
        </Request>
        <Condition>(proxy.pathsuffix MatchesPath &quot;/{cust_id}&quot;) and (request.verb = &quot;GET&quot;)</Condition>
        <Response/>
    </Flow>
</Flows>
<PostFlow name="PostFlow">
    <Response>
        <Step>
            <FaultRules/>
            <Name>Extracting-for-Stats</Name>
        </Step>
        <Step>
            <FaultRules/>
            <Name>Statistics-Collector-1</Name>
        </Step>
    </Response>
    <Request/>
</PostFlow>
<HTTPTargetConnection>
    <URL>https://api.usergrid.com/siddharth1/sandbox/icustomer</URL>
</HTTPTargetConnection>
</TargetEndpoint>
```

Extracting for Stats code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ExtractVariables async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true"     name="Extracting-for-Stats">
<DisplayName>Extracting for Stats</DisplayName>
<FaultRules/>
<Properties/>
 <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
<JSONPayload>
    <Variable name="customer_id">
        <JSONPath>$.entities[0].cust_id</JSONPath>
    </Variable>
</JSONPayload>
<Source clearPayload="false">response</Source>
<VariablePrefix>apigee</VariablePrefix>

</ExtractVariables>
```

Statistics Collector code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<StatisticsCollector async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Statistics-Collector-1">
<DisplayName>Statistics Collector 1</DisplayName>
<FaultRules/>
<Properties/>
<Statistics>
    <Statistic name="test_cust_id" ref="customer_id" type="STRING">NO_ID</Statistic>
</Statistics>
</StatisticsCollector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ExtractVariables specifies a VariablePrefix of "apigee". I would expect the extracted field to be accessible from `apigee.customer_id` instead of just `customer_id`, which would return null in the StatisticsCollector check. I think that's why you are getting your default "NO_ID".

Comment: I have tried "apigee.customer_id" still I'm getting default "NO_ID" in custom reports. I've  even tried only "customer_id" which gives "not set" in custom reports.

Comment: I have commented out the VariablePrefix and the reports are working. I'm getting the reports but out of 10 reports few reports are showing as "not set"

Comment: If your call to `https://api.usergrid.com/siddharth1/sandbox/icustomer` fails for any reason, you will jump to FaultRules instead of continuing with PostFlow, and you'll never reach your StatisticsCollector policy. You can attach StatisticCollector policies in your proxy and target fault rules to make sure it is always hit if you'd like.